# Siege startup error - unable to connect to socket

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, ubuntu, load-testing

I'm running a 64x Ubuntu 12.10 and trying to use siege 2.70.
The problem is when I'm trying to test ip address of my server or for example a google.com ip - 173.194.39.130

```
siege -g http://173.194.39.130
```

I get the following error:

```
[error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:222: Connection refused
```

And that's it.

When I do

```
siege -g http://www.google.com
```

I get the same error and a 200 valid response.

What could cause the problem ?

Comment: Get anywhere with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in earlier versions of Siege that prevented the use of IP addresses on certain systems.  By downloading and compiling the latest version of siege (>3) this issue should be resolved.

Comment: Compiling the latest version from source helped.